# Subclassing UITableViewCell & [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I'm trying understand how `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` works. Here is my situation:

I have designed my UITableViewCell subclass in IB and now I'm trying style my sub elements of the cell in my subclass. Unfortunately the method `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` seems to not call any method in my cells subclass. With methods I mean `initWithCoder`,`initWithFrame` or `init`.

This is my actual code:

```
static NSString *BasicCellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
GSFeedBasicTableViewCell *basicCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:BasicCellIdentifier];
```

My Cells are showing up but I would to customize the cell further in my subclass to avoid styling code in my TableController. Any hints are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When using XIB,you need to register first

   ```
   [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"IBNameofthiscell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"youridentifier"];
   ```

Then you can use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

2. If using storyboard,do not forget to set the class of this cell
   to your custom class,and set identifier to your identifier.

[image]

[image]

3.Then use this function

`CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: I'm using storyboard so theres no need for registering a nib, right?

Comment: what method do get called in my subclass when I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` ? Can you tell me this?

Comment: First,`initwithCoder` then `awakeFromNib`.If you are using IB or XIb

Answer (score 1):

When you dequeue a cell, your subclass's `initWithCoder:` method is called. So you can override it to implement custom behaviour. You can also perform your customization is the `awakeFromNib` method.

If you designed the cell completely in code, then the subclass's `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method will be called instead of `initWithCoder:`.